# Published files look like different from localhost

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, publish, http-status-code-403

So I published a web site via VS project -> publish web site -> ftp. And when I opened it I found everything was out of place,as if the site had no css at all. I started looking the HTML of site online and local version, right on top I did notice this:

**online:**

```
<title>
...
</title><script src="/bundles/modernizr?v=wBEWDufH_8Md-Pbioxomt90vm6tJN2Pyy9u9zHtWsPo1"></script>
<link href="/Content/css?v=0mo0uNbGUFWt4hgQ0AZZm5kcuaVkDkYEBh4UeS1mWi41" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
```

**localhost:**

```
<title>
...
</title><script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
<link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
```

The're supposed to be the same but looks like .NET merged the files of same extension in a single file. So far ok, I guess this is what   `<webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />` is for.
 But the file `/Content/css?v=0mo0uNbGUFWt4hgQ0AZZm5kcuaVkDkYEBh4UeS1mWi41` doesn't even open, it return an `403.14 - Forbidden` error

What's the cause of the error and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

All of your CSS files have been bundled into one file. This is not performed when you have debug="true" in the system.web compilation tag in your web.config file.

Turn it off, recompile, and then you should see the file locally.

Comment: How can I disable only the merge of files? I don't want to set debug true on release...

Comment: Remove all folders from Bundle.config.

Answer (score 1):

There's a file created by default in a webforms app called Bundle.config. It contains the definition for that missing css bundle. Have you deleted it, or is it missing from your published files? That could cause what you're seeing. I deleted mine and right away all of the css disappeared because now it's not matching that URL to a bundle.

It's called Bundle.config, it goes in the root folder, and it contains this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<bundles version="1.0">
  <styleBundle path="~/Content/css">
    <include path="~/Content/bootstrap.css" />
    <include path="~/Content/Site.css" />
  </styleBundle>
</bundles>
```

Comment: The file is there in root folder and its contents look like exactly this